# SciChart SCIRolloverModifier on tap

Tags: ios, swift, scichart

I'm using [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) on iOS application.

is it possible to show `SCIRolloverModifier` only on tap gesture? I want to avoid that fact that when dragging the chart, it automatically shows the Rollover.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is now an example of how to do this in SciChart iOS v2.x at the [SciChart.iOS.Examples](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples) Github repository

[SciChart.iOS.Examples > v2.x > Sandbox > LeaveRolloverOnScreen_Swift](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples/tree/master/v2.x/Sandbox/LeaveRolloverOnScreen_Swift)

How this works.

There is a class called CustomRollover which inherits SCIRolloverModifier. This overrides the onPanGesture and only calls the base class onPanGesture (which removes the rollover on touch end) if the gesture action has not ended

```
 class CustomRollover : SCIRolloverModifier {
    override func onPanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!, at view: UIView!) -> Bool {
        if (gesture.state != .ended) {
            return super.onPanGesture(gesture, at: view)
        }
        return true ;
    }
}
```

In the main view there is a button which adds the Rollover to the chart and removes it by adding/removing the CustomRollover from the SCIChartSurface.ChartModifiers collection.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 5, width: 200, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Add/Remove Rollover", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(button)

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        rollover.isEnabled = !rollover.isEnabled
        if (rollover.isEnabled) {
            self.chartModifiers.add(rollover)
        } else {
            self.chartModifiers.remove(rollover)
        }
    }
```

This is the easiest way to remove the rollover from the screen, and it lets you decide when you want it to be removed or hidden.